# How can I obtain only MSSQL rows that have been created since Jan 1st?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script that writes database information to a csv based on a SQL query I wrote. I was recently tasked with modifying the query to return only rows where the `DateTime` field has a date that is newer then Jan. 1 of this year. The following query does not work:

```
$startdate = "01/01/2013 00:00:00"

SELECT Ticket, Description, DateTime
FROM [table]
WHERE ((Select CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), DateTime,105) as [DD-MM-YYYY])>=(Select CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), $startdate,105) as [DD-MM-YYYY]))"
```

The format of the DateTime field in the database is in the same format as the $startdate variable. What am I doing wrong? Is my query incorrectly formated? Thanks.

Comment: because your converting the values to varchar and doing a string comparison instead of comparing actual dates.  05/01/2012 > 01/01/2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime

SELECT  @startdate = '01/01/2013'

SELECT  Ticket, Description, DateTime
FROM    [table]
WHERE   DateTime >= @startdate
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get year based records through [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime = '01/01/2013';
    SELECT Ticket, Description, DateTime
    FROM [table]
    WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR,@startdate,DateTime) = 0 //It gives 0 if years are the same and DateTime is your column
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the start of the current year using:

```
DateAdd( year, Year( GetDate() ) - 1900, 0 )
```

The query then becomes:

```
select Ticket, Description, [DateTime]
  from [Table]
  where [DateTime] >= DateAdd( year, Year( GetDate() ) - 1900, 0 )
```

If you really don't want rows from January first then change the comparison from `>=` to `>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime

SELECT  @startdate = '01/01/2013'

SELECT  Ticket, Description, DateTime
FROM    [table]
WHERE   DateTime >= @startdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question that says as much about interpreting the requirement as about the SQL. When next year comes you will want to select next year's tickets. So it should be

```
SELECT  Ticket, Description, DateTime
FROM    [table]
WHERE   datePart(yy,DateTime)=datePart(yy,getDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime = '01/01/2013';
    SELECT Ticket, Description, DateTime
    FROM [table]
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DD,@startdate,DateTime) >= 0
```